# Using external Library via Maven in Talend Routine

Tags: talend

I want to use the **Slugify Library** (https://github.com/slugify/slugify) in a custom **Talend routine**. I´ve already taken the following steps:

1. Added the dependency to Project Settings > Build > Maven > Default > Project
2. Added the import statement in my class header (import com.github.slugify.Slugify;)

But the compiler is not able to resolve the dependency to the Slugify library. Is there **a step I´m missing** (like importing the dependencies)?

Thanks in advance for any hint,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

In order to use an external library, you need to import the jar in your job using `tLibraryLoad` component. Only then will the compiler be able to resolve your imports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... What exactly is the maven import for if I have to import the jar manually?